# Nagios nrpe plugin install on remote host

Tags: nagios, nrpe, xinetd

On Centos7, following [nrpe plugin install steps](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe/blob/master/docs/NRPE.pdf), when testing the connection between the Nagios server and the remote agent, I got this error...

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.50.5
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not connect to 192.168.50.5: Connection reset by peer
```

In /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe, I added the Nagios server's IP address to the only_from field.

```
# default: off
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
    disable         = no
    socket_type     = stream
    port            = 5666
    wait            = no
    user            = nagios
    group           = nagios
    server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
    server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
    only_from       = 127.0.0.1 ::1 {server_IP}
    log_on_success  =
}
```

I then restarted the xinetd service; however, upon checking the service status this error log message appeared...

```
Aug 09 09:32:21 localhost.localdomain xinetd[1448]: bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = nrpe
Aug 09 09:32:21 localhost.localdomain xinetd[1448]: Service nrpe failed to start and is deactivated.
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to not only to include the server IP in /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe, but also to stop the nrpe service before restarting the xinetd service.

```
systemctl stop nrpe
systemctl restart xinetd
```

It seems restarting xinetd on its own failed to load the nrpe service because it the ports conflicted with the existing nrpe service.